# Multiple Row Update using JPA query or native sql query in spring boot app

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.1

Hi am trying to update multiple rows using a single query in a spring boot application .
I have a map in which key returns the id of row and value is the value to be updated for that key. The value to be updated for a key are different .

I am unable to form a query to update mutiple rows using that Map . A pseudo code has been attached . I am using PostgresSQL 12.1

```
Map<String,String> a;
@Query("UPDATE tableName set columnA=:valueList where columnB=:keyList",nativeQuery=true)
public void updateQ(List<String> keyList, List<String> valueList);
```

Comment: I think you need to use batch update, You can do it easily by using spring jdbc template

Answer (score 0):

Using a native query, you could write a few lines of code to loop through the map and generate something like the following query.

```
UPDATE
   TABLE_NAME
SET
   TABLE_NAME.VALUE_COLUMN = table2.valueColumn
FROM
   TABLE_NAME table1
INNER JOIN
   (select * FROM (VALUES ('key1','value1'),('key2','value2'),('key3','value3')) as staticTable (keyColumn , valueColumn)) table2
ON
   table1.KEY_COLUMN = table2.keyColumn
```

I would suggest you look into other options though, if you plan on updating hundreds of records at once.